# Get the current date in java.sql.Date format

Tags: java, jdbc, java.util.date

I need to add the current date into a prepared statement of a JDBC call. I need to add the date in a format like `yyyy/MM/dd`.

I've try with

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd");
Date date = new Date();
pstm.setDate(6, (java.sql.Date) date);
```

but I have this error:

```
threw exception
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

Is there a way to obtain a `java.sql.Date` object with the same format?

Comment: Depending on your use-case, you might not want to send the date from the client. Instead, have an insert trigger on the table to set the column to "now" on the db server side. This way you can have a consistent server side timestamp, protect yourself from client side clock/timezone problems, and have new records still have the date updated if the records are inserted from a different client app or addhoc transaction.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

A `java.util.Date` is not a `java.sql.Date`.  It's the other way around.  A `java.sql.Date` is a `java.util.Date`.

You'll need to convert it to a `java.sql.Date` by using the [constructor that takes a `long`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Date.html#Date%28long%29) that a `java.util.Date` can supply.

```
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
```

Comment: What about the current date?

Comment: @Yster The question already had the current date: `Date date = new Date();`.  It's about converting a `java.util.Date` to a `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: For simplicity's sake: java.sql.Date sqlDate = new java.sql.Date(System.currentTimeMillis());

Comment: downvote - no idea what a utilDate is or how your code is meant to compile. unclear.

Comment: @bharal The naming convention is quite clearly "sqlDate" and "utilDate" (`java.sql.Date`, `java.util.Date`). The code compiles in any block in which a `java.util.Date` exists with the name "utilDate". The question was about converting a date, implying one already exists.

Comment: java.sql.Date is deprecated !!

Comment: @AhmedElbatt but the answer is still valid. The question asks how to convert one Class to the other.

Answer (score 54):

These are all too long.

Just use:

```
new Date(System.currentTimeMillis())
```

Comment: How can I get it to this format 2020-05-27T16:28:15.759+0200 and not as it is 2020-05-27 ?          Thanks

Comment: If you're wanting an offset, you'll likely need to be using OffsetDateTime class and persisting it as a string. However, be warned that offsets will have trouble with daylight savings.

Answer (score 46):

Simply in one line:

```
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());
```

Comment: why does that give me always midnight time and not current time?

Comment: for time you need `java.sql.Time time = new java.sql.Time(Calendar.getInstance().getTime().getTime());`

Answer (score 22):

```
new java.sql.Date(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
```

Answer (score 6):

In order to get "the current date" (as in today's date), you can use `LocalDate.now()` and pass that into the `java.sql.Date` method `valueOf(LocalDate)`.

```
import java.sql.Date;
...
Date date = Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now());
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the java.sql.Date has a constructor that takes 'long time' and java.util.Date has a method that returns 'long time', I just pass the returned 'long time' to the java.sql.Date to create the date.

```
java.util.Date date = new java.util.Date();
java.sql.Date sqlDate = new Date(date.getTime());
```

Answer (score 3):

## tl;dr

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject(   // Directly exchange java.time objects with database without the troublesome old java.sql.* classes.
    … ,                                   
    LocalDate.parse(             // Parse string as a `LocalDate` date-only value.
        "2018-01-23"             // Input string that complies with standard ISO 8601 formatting.
    ) 
)
```

## java.time

The modern approach uses the *java.time* classes that supplant the troublesome old legacy classes such as `java.util.Date` and `java.sql.Date`.

For a date-only value, use `LocalDate`. The [`LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html) class represents a date-only value without time-of-day and without time zone.

The java.time classes use standard formats when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( input ) ;
```

You can directly exchange *java.time* objects with your database using a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. You can forget about transforming in and out of java.sql.* classes.

```
myPreparedStatement.setObject( … , ld ) ;
```

Retrieval:

```
LocalDate ld = myResultSet.getObject( … , LocalDate.class ) ;
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 3):

Will do:
`new Date(Instant.now().toEpochMilli())`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve you goal with below ways :-

```
long millis=System.currentTimeMillis();  
java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(millis);
```

**or**

```
// create a java calendar instance
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

// get a java date (java.util.Date) from the Calendar instance.
// this java date will represent the current date, or "now".
java.util.Date currentDate = calendar.getTime();

// now, create a java.sql.Date from the java.util.Date
java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(currentDate.getTime());
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is this

```
    Calendar currenttime = Calendar.getInstance();               //creates the Calendar object of the current time
    Date sqldate = new Date((currenttime.getTime()).getTime());  //creates the sql Date of the above created object
    pstm.setDate(6, (java.sql.Date) date);              //assign it to the prepared statement (pstm in this case)
```