# How can I create an update query that change the value of a field with the sysdate?

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jakarta-ee, jdbc

I am working on a Java application that perform query on the DB using JDBC and I have the following problem with a very simple **update** query.

So I have this query (acytually incomplete):

```
sb.append("UPDATE coda_tx c SET c.FK_STATO = ");
sb.append(newStatus);
sb.append(",c.DATA_OUT = ");
sb.append(???)
sb.append(" WHERE c.PK_CODA = ");
sb.append(pkCoda);
```

So this query have simple to update 2 fields of the **coda_tx** table.

The **FK_STATO** field update is not a problem (it is update with a string and it works fine, I tryied in a previous query verion) but I don't know how to correctly update the **DATA_OUT** field that is a **DATE** SQL field.

In the specific I have that it is updated with the **sysdate**, it say:

- CODA_TX.data_out = sysdate

So I think that it have to be update with the current date retrieved from Java. Is it right or am I missing something? What exactly is this **sysdate**? How can I correctly retrieve and use it?

What hava I to put instead the **???** into **sb.append(???)** to update the field?

Tnx

Comment: perhaps this might help?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18257648/get-the-current-date-in-java-sql-date-format

Comment: Not relevant to the question, but why aren't you using bind variables to set `newStatus` and `pkCoda`?

Comment: What Alex is getting at is that you're vulnerable to SQL injection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use the system date value from the database. Use:

```
c.DATA_OUT = sysdate
```

in the `update` statement.

Comment: So, in my previous query, I can do sb.append(sysdate); or what?

Comment: @AndreaNobili - no, `sysdate` is a database function, not something Java knows about; so either `sb.append("sysdate")` or include it in the previous append (and merge the following one too, perhaps).